# Does a continuous map $f$ from the $n$-ball $B$ into $R^n$ such that $B\subset f(B)$ have a fixed point?

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, fixed-point-theorems

If $f$ is a continuous map from the $n$-ball $B$ into itself, the Brouwer fixed point theorem guarantees a fixed point. What if we assume that $f$ maps $B$ into all $R^n$, and $f(B)$ contains $B$? For the one-dimensional case it is still true that such $f$ has a fixed point. Does this property also hold for higher dimensions?

Answer (score 11):

Edit: I'm retaining my original answer below, but here is a simpler formula which builds on Goldstern's modification of my answer.

Work in the complex plane. Let
$$A = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 \leq |z| \leq 2\mbox{ and }0 \leq {\rm arg}(z) \leq \pi\}.$$
This set is homeomorphic to the unit ball, so for topological questions like the existence of fixed points the change is inessential.

Define $f: A \to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z) = iz^2$. Then the image under $f$ of the part of $A$ with argument between $0$ and $\pi/4$ is $\{z: 1 \leq |z| \leq 4$ and $\pi/2 \leq {\rm arg}(z) \leq \pi\}$, and the image of the part of $A$ with argument between $3\pi/4$ and $\pi$ is $\{z: 1 \leq |z| \leq 4$ and $0 \leq {\rm arg}(z) \leq \pi/2\}$. The rest of $A$ maps into the lower half-plane. So the image of $A$ contains $A$, and it is obvious from looking at arguments that there are no fixed points.

(The alternative formula $f(z) = iz^2/|z|$ would eliminate the radial stretching, if one prefers this.)

Original answer below.

---

This fails for $n = 2$. For simplicity consider the unit square $C = [0,1]^2$ instead of $B$. Then define $f$ by first setting $f(x,y) = (x + 1/2, y)$ for $(x,y) \in C$ with $x \leq 1/2$ --- this shifts the left half of the square onto the right half, no fixed points there. Define $f(x,y) = (2x - 3/2, y)$ for $(x,y) \in C$ with $x \geq 3/4$ --- this takes the right one-fourth of $C$ onto the left half, again no fixed points. Then the middle strip $[1/2, 3/4] \times [0,1]$ can be stretched around over the top of the square to complete the definition of a continuous map. I have a hard time describing that last step without drawing a picture, is it clear?

Comment: You may be able to use something like (z+c)^n for a well chosen complex c and integer n for the map, and show that (z+c)^n - z "has large roots".  Gerhard "Not Ready For Such Complexity" Paseman, 2015.07.13

Comment: Yes, it is clear, thanks. I guess when you do the stretching and over-the-top construction, you take care to get agreement with the previous definition, over the top boundary of the square.

Comment: Very nice example. I don't think this is general knowledge. I would like your permission to quote the example (including your autorship) in a work done by a student on Sharkovskii's theorem.

Comment: @JuanTolosa: yes, of course.

Comment: The new answer is even nicer than mine.

Comment: It is also immediate to find the fixed points of f algebraically; they are 0 and -i; neither is in A.

Answer (score 5):

(Really just a comment on Nik Weaver's answer, but too long for a comment)

The same idea with a different (more easily expressible) parametrization:  Use polar coordinates, and 
consider the "square"  $D:=\{(r,\psi):  \frac12 \le r \le 1, 0\le \psi \le \alpha\}$, with some small angle $\alpha$.

- For $0\le\psi \le\frac14 \alpha$, map $(r,\psi)$ to $(r,\frac12\alpha + 2\psi)$, covering the region between $\frac12\alpha$ and $\alpha$.
- For $\frac34 \alpha\le\psi\le \alpha$, map $(r,\psi)$ to $(r,2*(\psi-\frac34\alpha))$, covering the region between $0$ and $\frac12\alpha$.
- For $\frac 14 \alpha\le \psi\le \frac34\alpha$, map $(r,\psi)$ to $(r, c(\psi-\frac14\alpha)+d)$, with $d:=\alpha$ and $c\cdot\frac12\alpha+d=2\pi$.

Comment: Ah, that is nicer.